# Applications of analytic combinatorics

Tags: analysis-of-algorithms, analytic-combinatorics

At the beginning of "Analytic Combinatorics" by Flajolet and Sedgewick, there's some discussion about the "usefulness" of the book's techniques in the analysis of algorithms and computational biology. However, I've struggled to find recent papers that employ techniques from analytic combinatorics, as well as to find any faculty members (at any university) who specialize in this. I'm just curious what kinds of problems people who apply these techniques are solving, so I suppose my question is: what examples do you have of analytic combinatorics being applied to computational biology or analysis of algorithms?